# Shared base for NodeJS microservices

Tags: node.js, docker, automation, architecture, microservices

After doing a bit of research i found quite some information on how to generally develop NodeJS/docker based microservices. But i still wonder what would be a good approach to provide a common base for a collection of NodeJS microservices that already includes some dependencies and even some architecture/structure presets.

Requirements for every microservice that uses the microservice base would be:

- include testing frameworks with execution entry points for every type of tests
- update of the base should update every microservice that is dependent on it
- use versions of technologies and frameworks defined in the base microservice
- shared scripts/automation

Thanks for the help!

I was thinking of wrapping some custom code in external repositories that i could include inside the package.json, but that doesn’t seem to be the ideal solution yet.